# Error Deployment on jboss-as-7.1.1.Final Xalan

Tags: java, deployment, jboss, ear, xalan

On  jboss-as-7.1.1.Final, i have a problem of classpath , when deploying the EAR I have his error :

```
WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) Class Path entry xercesImpl.jar in "/C:/dev/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/bin/content/appli.ear/lib/xalan-2.7.1-1.jbossorg.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) Class Path entry xml-apis.jar in "/C:/dev/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/bin/content/appli.ear/lib/xalan-2.7.1-1.jbossorg.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) Class Path entry serializer.jar in "/C:/dev/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/bin/content/appli.ear/lib/xalan-2.7.1-1.jbossorg.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
```

How can I resolve it ?

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is saying that in file "xalan-2.7.1-1.jbossorg.jar" there is a MANIFEST.MF file in META-INF folder that contains Classpath entries that are not valid.

It is not an error, it's just a warning.

However, you don't really want to change those manually. If you have the files in classpath by another name and want to keep it that way, you can do that. However, with JBoss 7.1.1, those files should be included in modules as well, so you can use jboss-deployment-structure.xml to import those from modules and remove them from your ear. It can have other consequences though. xalan/xerces libraries are easily broken.

If your only problem is the warning message and everything works otherwise fine, I'd just ignore it.

Comment: I don't know really if my problem come from this warning so I have thinked that may be it's the cause. When I use a function of the library Xalan(For example PrintTraceListener ptl = new PrintTraceListener(pw) ) I got this error : `Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xalan/trace/PrintTraceListener`.... `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xalan.trace.TraceListener from [Module "deployment.SATest.ear.sa.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
`

Comment: @user1814879 ah. so you have really a xalan configuration issue with JBoss. Those are nasty ones, but you should really rewrite your question to discuss about the xalan configuration issue, not the warnings. Warnings don't matter, your xalan configuration problems do.

Comment: Ok it's here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27943766/xalan-configuration-jboss