# Xalan Configuration JBOSS

Tags: java, jboss, xalan

In Using Xalan I get this error when I call a  function of this library (For example : PrintTraceListener ptl = new PrintTraceListener(pw) ) I got this error in console

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xalan.trace.PrintTraceListener from [Module "deployment.ReceptionPartenairesSATest.ear.sa.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
                    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
                ....
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xalan/trace/PrintTraceListener
                    at fr.recouv.cfe.sa.impl.NairesSAImpl.transformXSL(NairesSAImpl.java:333) [classes:]
                    at fr.recouv.cfe.sa.impl.NairesSAImpl.transformToLas(NairesSAImpl.java:290) [classes:]
                .....
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.WeldException: org/apache/xalan/trace/PrintTraceListener
                at org.jboss.weld.bean.InterceptorImpl.intercept(InterceptorImpl.java:92) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
                at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.DelegatingInterceptorInvocationContext.proceed(DelegatingInterceptorInvocationContext.java:71) [jboss-as-weld-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
```

Comment: you are expected to provide a reproducable test case. You could start by describing your deployment package. what are you packaging in your .ear and why? Also stuff like jboss version etc are relevant.

Comment: Solution is to add manually in my test class the jar of xalan for add it at the deployment :  `war.addAsLibrary(new File("C:/dev/maven/repository/xalan/xalan/2.7.1.jbossorg-1/xalan-2.7.1.jbossorg-1.jar"));`

Comment: so you're using Arquillian.... you could have actually mentioned it in the question